# Scheme: Convert atoms in a list to symbols

Tags: recursion, scheme, token, symbols

I'm trying to implement a recursive function that converts every number to N, every symbol to S, and every time it finds a sublist, the chars I and D are added, at the beginning and at the end of the sublist.

Example: (tokens '(1 (a (2 b) 5))) => (N I S I N S D N D D)

Right now I've got this code:

```
;delete parentheses
(define (delete atm lis)
  (cond
     ((null? lis) '())
     ((symbol? lis) lis)
     ((eq? atm (car lis)) (delete atm (cdr lis)))
     (else (cons (car lis) (delete atm (cdr lis))))))

(define (tok l)
   (cond [(null? l) ()]
     [(number? (car l)) (cons 'N (tok (cdr l)))]
     [(symbol? (car l)) (cons 'S (tok (cdr l)))]
     [ else (cons (cons 'I (tok (car l))) (cons (tok (cdr l)) (cons 'D '())))]
     ))

(define (tokens l) 
   (delete '() (tok l))
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it!

```
(define (tokens l)
(cond [(null? l) ()]
     [(number? (car l)) (cons 'N (tokens (cdr l)))]
     [(symbol? (car l)) (cons 'S (tokens (cdr l)))]
     [ else (append (append (cons 'I (tokens (car l))) (cons 'D '())) (tokens (cdr l)))]
     ))
```

Comment: I'd suggest testing if `(pair? (car l))`, and add an `else` clause if not. Also, note that using `append` should be avoided because it is not very performant, but this adds the extra complexity of my solution. `(cons 'D '())` can be changed to `(list 'D)`. Nevertheless, +1 for simplifying your initial code that much!

Answer (score 1):

What you call "deleting parentheses" is commonly called "flattening" - creating a flat list from nested lists. So the best start for this is a working `flatten` procedure; my favourite one is the following:

```
(define (flatten sxp)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp) (res '()))
    (cond
      ((null? sxp) res)
      ((pair? sxp) (loop (car sxp) (loop (cdr sxp) res)))
      (else        (cons sxp res)))))
```

testing:

```
> (flatten '(1 (a (2 b) 5)))
'(1 a 2 b 5)
```

Now we need to do 2 more things:

1. replace numbers with `'N`, symbols with `'S`
2. surround sublists with `'I` and `'D`

For part 1, this is a small change in the `else` part of the above `cond`:

```
(else   (cons (cond
                 ((number? sxp) 'N)
                 ((symbol? sxp) 'S)
                 (else          sxp))
              res)))))
```

Part 2 is trickier, depending on your `flatten` procedure. Mine works on cons cells, so the start of a sublist is identified by the `car` of the cons cell being a list. Redundant use of `(car sxp)` is replaced by a binding to `c` in a `let` expression:

```
((pair? sxp) (let ((c (car sxp)))
               (if (list? c)
                   (cons 'I (loop c (cons 'D (loop (cdr sxp) res))))
                   (loop c (loop (cdr sxp) res)))))
```

Wrapping it all up:

```
(define (tokens sxp)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp) (res '()))
    (cond
      ((null? sxp) res)
      ((pair? sxp) (let ((c (car sxp)))
                     (if (list? c)
                         (cons 'I (loop c (cons 'D (loop (cdr sxp) res))))
                         (loop c (loop (cdr sxp) res)))))
      (else        (cons (cond
                           ((number? sxp) 'N)
                           ((symbol? sxp) 'S)
                           (else          sxp))
                         res)))))
```

testing:

```
> (tokens '(1 (a (2 b) 5)) )
'(N I S I N S D N D)
```

Note that I have one `'D` less than in your example because `'I` and `'D`s should balance.

Comment: This looks more like `#!racket` than Scheme. Neither `cons?` nor `null` are defined in Scheme.

Comment: @Sylwester Just replace `cons?` with `pair?`, and `null` with `'()`. Will that work in your implementation? I always find it strange that RnRS has `null?` but not `null`, and `cons` but not `cons?`.

Comment: Yes. I agree that it's strange, but Sussman probably didn't want to rename `cons` to `pair`.

Comment: @Sylwester Well then he would have had to rename *cons cells* to *pair cells* as well ;-)

Comment: Thanks @uselpa! I've got a question though, I'm trying to represent what you've done in a recursive way and find myself unable to do it. If you could please help me. I also don't use let nor res. I believe let creates constants that can't be modified and res must be the delimiter of the loop. If I'm wrong please correct me I'd like to learn.

Comment: @Vesper `let` creates a binding, and indeed it is not modified here (but it could, using `set!`). I just use it to avoid repeating `(car sxp)`, but it's not strictly necessary, just substitute `(car sxp)` for `c`.

Comment: @Vesper `res` is a binding, the name is supposed to mean "result". Very often you also find the name `acc` (which means accumulator) instead. This is a useful concept either to avoid (non-tail) recursion, or, in this case, for flattening a result. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Example_programs) for example.